# how to hide a column (number) data in view?

Tags: c3.js

i was working with c3.js to draw a graph.
each thing goes well except i cannot find the way to hide a column(integer value) data when show in chart.

the example src is simple like this：

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['myindex',100,200,300,400,500,600],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
        ['oth','a1','b2','c3','d4','ef','gh'],
    ],
    order: null,
    type: 'bar',
    groups:[["data1","data2"]],
    hide:["myindex",'oth'],
},
legend: {
    show: true,
    hide:["myindex","oth"],
},
subchart: {
    show: true
},
```

});

=====================

the result shows:
[result chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmbkj.png)

=====================
in this code i have a column data 'myindex'(i need to use it to custom tips) but don't want to show it in chart. i just want it to show like the subchart view.
could anyone help telling me how to fix it?

Comment: in the chart ,the blue bar shows the 'myindex' column data which i want to hide,

Answer (score 0):

i think i find a way to fix it，though i think it is not official.

ref: 
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/c3js/hide$20data|sort:date/c3js/6LHWvbuHBt4/9V1sXDUIKUMJ

================================

```
.c3-target-myindex{opacity: 0 !important;}
```

================================

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying the `chart.x` attribute when generating the chart?

You can see an example here: [C3 Example](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html)

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'myindex',
        columns: [
            ['myindex',100,200,300,400,500,600],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
            ['oth','a1','b2','c3','d4','ef','gh'],
        ],
        order: null,
        type: 'bar',
        groups:[["data1","data2"]],
        hide:["myindex",'oth'],
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        hide:["myindex","oth"],
    },
    subchart: {
        show: true
    },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id=chart></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i use 'myindex'  to associate with other data in my datastruct（for  custom tips or get other info），the real x axis is a datetime-formatted data something likes ‘2018-09-26 17:14:38'. so this method is not suitable for my situation.

Comment: i think the real problem is  why a number-formatted data can not be exactly hide in chart view while it is shown perfect in subchart.

Comment: So, do you want to **hide** the indexes from the _subchart_ or from the _main chart_ view?